# is there there way to access stylus AST

Tags: css, abstract-syntax-tree, stylus

I need to access the abstract-syntax-tree (AST) of the CSS style generated by stylus without parsing it again (through css-parse).
I wondering if the AST of the generated styles is publicly available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a partial support for accessing AST. It's incomplete, but still could be used in some cases.

Here is a basic example of how to do this — https://gist.github.com/kizu/41f40714ea533ee1f876

The crucial part is:

```
var Parser = require('stylus').Parser;
var parser = new Parser(stylContent);
var ast = parser.parse();
```

And you'll get the AST from the `stylContent` that contains the Stylus code.

In the future (Stylus 1.0.0) we're planning to make accessing AST easier and it would be more complete.